# Ubuntu 14.04.1 bluetooth does not detect any device

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, device, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed ubuntu today. In the beginning bluetooth was working. I mean it was at least showing devices. I did not do any big changes that would affect bluetooth. Now my bluetooth is not detecting anything. I have installed ubuntu in the morning and have spent whole day for searching solution. I tried many suggestions on the forums but none worked for me. It just does not find devices. Everything seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't given enough details for anyone to help you in any meaningful way. What does "not find devices" mean? What commands are you running? Are you using an inbuilt BT adapter or a dongle? What troubleshooting steps have you gone through? That's just some of the info you would need to provide. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help you.

Comment: @AlanAu Thanks for your reply. If you have never had this type of problem please dont waste your time with this question. Only those who had this problem knows it. And it is not easy to help if you did not fix similar problem yourself. I am telling that it is new latest ubuntu installation. Bluetooth was working after install. I did install chromium and changed localization settings and just folder view settings. I run update/upgrade commands. After that I was not able to see any devices in bluetooth 'Search device' panel. It just cannot find any device, but my smartphone can find 2 devices